# How to check gcp pupsub empty/inactitve subscribtion

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have an application that subscribes to a topic in GCP and when there is some messages over there it downloads them and sends them to a queue on ActiveMQ.

In order to make this process fast I am using exeutorService and launching multiple threads for sending messages to active mq. since that the subscription is supposed to be an ongoing task Iam putting the code in a while(true) loop.

I am searching for an elegant way to shutdown the executorService when the subscription is empty (no data in the topic) for like 2 or 3 minutes. and then of course it starts again when there is some new data.

the following will be my idea which I don't like. Iam looking for a more elegant way of doing that.

```
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class PubSubSubscriberService {

    private static final int EMPTY_SUBSCRIPTION_COUNTER = 4;
    private static final Logger businessLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("BusinessLogger");
    private Queue<PubsubMessage> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    


   public void pullMessagesAndSendToBroker(CompositeConfigurationElement cce) {

    var patchSize = cce.getSubscriber().getPatchSize();
    var nThreads = cce.getSubscriber().getSendingParallelThreads();
    var scheduledTasks = 0;
    var subscribeCounter = 0;
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = null;


    while (true) {
        try {
            if (subscribeCounter < EMPTY_SUBSCRIPTION_COUNTER) {
                log.info("Creating Executor Service for uploading to broker with a thread pool of Size: " + nThreads);
                threadPoolExecutor = getThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads);
            }

            var subscriber = this.getSubscriber(cce);
            this.startSubscriber(subscriber, cce);
            this.checkActivity(threadPoolExecutor, subscribeCounter++);


            // send patches of {{ messagesPerIteration }}
            while (this.messages.size() > patchSize) {
                if (poolIsReady(threadPoolExecutor, nThreads)) {
                    UploadTask task = new UploadTask(this.messages, cce, cf, patchSize);
                    threadPoolExecutor.submit(task);
                    scheduledTasks ++;
                }
                subscribeCounter = 0;
            }

            // send the rest
            if (this.messages.size() > 0) {
                UploadTask task = new UploadTask(this.messages, cce, cf, patchSize);
                threadPoolExecutor.submit(task);
                scheduledTasks ++;
                subscribeCounter = 0;
            }

            if (scheduledTasks > 0) {
                businessLogger.info("Scheduled " + scheduledTasks + " upload tasks of size upto: " + patchSize + ", preparing to start subscribing for 30 more sec") ;
                scheduledTasks = 0;
            }
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            businessLogger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```